# How to remove this extra part at the right?

Tags: css

I want to create a dropdown menu :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />   
    <title>Simply Styled jQuery Dropdown</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"/>            
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.1.min.js"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.dropdownPlain.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>          
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li class="menuppal"><a href="#">Administration</a>
                <ul>
                     <li><a href="#">Artificial Turf</a></li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="#">Batting Cages</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Indoor</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Outdoor</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                     <li><a href="#">Benches &amp; Bleachers</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Communication Devices</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Dugouts</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Fencing &amp; Windscreen</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Floor Protectors</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Foul Poles</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Netting</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Outdoor Furniture</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Outdoor Signs</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Padding</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Scoreboards</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Shade Structures</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"> - VIEW ALL - </a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menuppal"><a href="#">Structure</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">All-in-One Team Cart</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Air &amp; Electrical Reels</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Field Drags</a></li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="#">Field Marking Equipment</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Batter's Box Templates</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Dryline Markers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Field Paint</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Field Sprayers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Stencils</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="#">Field Tarps</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Area Tarps</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Growth Covers / Protectors</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Infield Tarps</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Tarp Accessories</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                     <li><a href="#">Hand Tools</a></li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="#">Irrigation, Hoses, Nozzles</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Hoses &amp; Hose Reels</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Irrigation</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Nozzles</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                     <li><a href="#">Layout Tools</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Moisture Removal</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Mound Fortification</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Mowers &amp; Stripers</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Soil Management</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Soil Amendments</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Spreaders &amp; Sweepers</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"> - VIEW ALL - </a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menuppal"><a href="#">Exercice</a>
                <ul>
                     <li>
                        <a href="#">Baseball - Softball</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Base Accessories</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Bases &amp; Home Plates</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Game Accessories</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Pitching Rubbers</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="#">Batting Practice Equipment</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Backstops</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Infield Screens</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Jugs Pitching Machines</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Turf Mats</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Turf Protectors</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Replacement Accessories</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="#">Batting Cages</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Indoor</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Outdoor</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="#">Portable Mounds</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Batting Practice Mounds</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Game Mounds</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Practice Mounds</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="#">Football</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">First Down Markers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Football Accessories</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Football Goalposts</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="#">Soccer</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Soccer Goals</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Soccer Accessories</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                     <li><a href="#"> - VIEW ALL - </a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menuppal"><a href="#">Contribuables et biens</a>
                <ul>
                     <li><a href="#">Ladders &amp; Sticks</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Hurdles</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Training Accessories</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Smart-Cart Training System</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Smart-Hurdle Collection</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"> - VIEW ALL - </a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menuppal"><a href="#">Recettes</a>
                <ul>
                     <li><a href="#">Field Design</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Turf Management</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Training</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"> - VIEW ALL - </a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menuppal"><a href="#">Edition</a>
                <ul>
                     <li><a href="#">Field Design</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Turf Management</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Training</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"> - VIEW ALL - </a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menuppal"><a href="#">Outils</a>
                <ul>
                     <li><a href="#">Field Design</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Turf Management</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Training</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#"> - VIEW ALL - </a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>       
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The css is :

```
 * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 100;
    width: 100%;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

/*
 LEVEL ONE : MAIN MENU
 */
ul.dropdown {
    position: relative;
}

ul.dropdown li.menuppal {
    float: left;
    zoom: 1;
    background: #000 url(../images/menuLight.png) repeat-x top left;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-left: 1px solid #222;
}

ul.dropdown li.menuppal a {
    display: block;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    color: #000000;
}

 /* Doesn't work in IE */
ul.dropdown li.menuppal:hover {
    background: #ccc url('../images/menuDark.png') repeat-x 50% 50%;
    position: relative;
}
/*
        FIN LEVEL ONE
 */

/*
 LEVEL TWO
 */
ul.dropdown ul {
    width: 220px;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #40617C;
}

ul.dropdown ul li {
    float: none;
}

/* IE 6 & 7 Needs Inline Block */
ul.dropdown li.menuppal ul li a {
    border-right: none;
    color: #FFF;
    display: inline-block;
}

ul.dropdown  li.menuppal ul li a:hover {
    background: #07243a;
}

ul.dropdown  li.menuppal ul li a:visited {
    word-break: break-all;
}
/*
        FIN LEVEL TWO
 */
```

At runtime there is an extra width at the right of the menu when I pass the mouse over it :

[image]

So how to remove this extra ?

Comment: You should have provided full code or a jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have both `width` and `padding` set, so give `box-sizing`:

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 100;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the following styles:

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 100;
  width: 100%;
}

ul.dropdown li.menuppal ul li a {
  border-right: none;
  color: #FFF;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul.dropdown li.menuppal a {
    display: block;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    color: #000000;
}
```

As you have `padding` and `width:100%` it will make your anchor extend beyond 100%.  The following will fix it:

```
ul.dropdown li.menuppal a {
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

[More information about box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)